# Merge Tuples in a list - Spacy Trainset related

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a 'n'(10K or more) tuples in a list like the following below (SpaCy's training format) -

```
[
('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG')]}),
('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})
]
```

The plan is to group same sentences and merge the dictionaries. I obviously went for the brute-force looping idea but that is very slow if I have 10-25K data. Any better/optimal ways to do this?

Desired output -

```
[('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG'), (36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})]
```

Comment: What do you need the output to look like?

Comment: Updated the question with the same.

Comment: Hi @RithwikRajendran can you please post a bit larger input, I have an approach in mind that I want to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that `str` in python can be hashed/indexed.

Here I am using a dictionary with key as the string or 1st element of your tuple

If you have memory limitations, you can batch it out OR use open-source platform like Google Colab

```
temp = [
('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG')]}),
('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})
]
data = {}
for i in temp:
    if i[0] in data:data[i[0]]['entities'].append(i[1]['entities'][0])
    else: data[i[0]]= i[1]
temp = [(k,v) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(data.items())]
print(temp)
```

```
[('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG'), (36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll just need to sort the tuples in the dictionary now :-) Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Since the sentences are your keys, a dict is a natural way to do this. For every entry in the list, append the entity tuple to a running list for that sentence, like so:

```
itemlist = [
    ('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG')]}),
    ('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})
]

sentence_dict = {}
for item in itemlist:
    sentence = item[0]
    entity = item[1]['entities'][0]  # Get the tuple from the list which is the value for entities
    value_dict = sentence_dict.get(sentence, {'entities': []})
    value_dict['entities'].append(entity)
    sentence_dict[sentence] = value_dict

list_of_tuples = []
for sentence, entity_dict in sentence_dict.items():
    list_of_tuples.append((sentence, entity_dict))

>>> print(list_of_tuples)
[('Apple are selling their products on Amazon', {'entities': [(0, 5, 'PROD-ORG'), (36, 42, 'ECOM-ORG')]})]
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!